# HTML Form where element name="something[]", how to assign input values to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

WHen I execute this in Chrome Console:

```
document.getElementsByName("input_44[]")
```

It returns an array of HTML:

```
<input type=​"number" maxlength=​"2" name=​"input_44[]​" id=​"input_1_44_1" value tabindex=​"54" min=​"0" max=​"24" step=​"1">​, <input type=​"number" maxlength=​"2" name=​"input_44[]​" id=​"input_1_44_2" value tabindex=​"55" min=​"0" max=​"59" step=​"1">​
```

I can pass this array into PHP.  My question comes after that.  I have a PHP variable that I would like to assign the same as what is returned by Chrome Console execution of `document.getElementsByName("input_44[]")[0].value`

Given the input, would PHP have enough information to declare a variable and assign its value to the equivalent of `document.getElementsByName("input_44[]")[0].value` ?

Thank you,

Comment: class DomDovument ?

Comment: If the value is transferred to PHP as part of a request, it would.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do